# Any libraries exist for easy configuration via USB?

Tags: serial, usb, stm32

I have a device that would really benefit from a USB configuration tool. I'm envisioning "plug it into a PC, and it appears as a storage device with a YAML config file". Are there any ready-made libraries to do this, or some other established way of configuring an Arduino-based product with a PC?

I'm developing with PlatformIO on an STM32 Blackpill, if that matters.

Comment: there are examples of using a microcontroller to emulate a USB storage device available on the internet